# OS level event handling?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I want to handle os level events in java. I need to do is to perform some logic on key press. I find jni is used for this purpose but don't know how. I don't need to handle event on gui. my application will run on background and perform some logic on every key press.

Answer (score 0):

If you think using a GUI is overkill, I wouldn't consider using JNI which will be 10x harder. Even if you are confident in C, it can be tricky.

You are better off using a library which does what you want already like http://jline.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I need to handle events on key press from keyboard. i.e when any key is pressed it cause inturpetion in os. No matter either user in on my application or on other, wherever it press key from keyboard, it will get by my application. i want this.? I never find this type of functionality in jline.

Comment: So you want to have a spyware keylogger in Java?

Comment: exactly. I can't find any thing useful on net. please help me if you are familiar with such type of thing. Thnaks

Comment: I would be concerned that it might be used for something illegal, immoral or as an invasion of privacy. I am sure you wouldn't do such a thing but I cannot encourage it.

Comment: Don't worry man. it just an assignment for me. I'll never use it for immoral activity.